# Problems with SetCPU on Sidekick 4G

Tags: setcpu, t-mobile-sidekick-4g

I installed SetCPU on my SK4G today, and for the most part things are running fine and I haven't had any problems.

At first I was getting a lot of lag and my phone kept freezing, so I checked [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/830/im-new-to-setcpu-on-moto-droid-and-need-help) post and it helped me out a lot.

But I ran into one more problem. My phone keeps shutting off and I have to take out the battery and put it back in order to turn it on again. It's happened twice.

Could SetCPU be the cause of the problem?

**Profiles:**

Main / 816max - 312min (ondemand)

Temp > 35.6 C / 608max - 216min (ondemand / priority: 100)

Charging / 760max - 456min (ondemand / priority: 75)

Screen Off / 456max - 312min (ondemand / priority: 50)

I should also mention that I don't have a custom ROM or Kernel on my phone. It's just rooted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely yes. I have a SK4G as well, and tried SetCPU out too.  It force closed regularly; whether it's due to overheating I can't say for sure, but it seems the most likely cause.

FYI, all the SK4G ROMs are based on the stock ROM as no one's reverse-engineered the hardware requirements to build custom kernels for it yet :(

Comment: Ah, that's good to know. I thought there were some custom Kernel's available for it, but I guess I read wrong on xda. I wish I'd gone with one of the Galaxy S phones. It seems like people have put more work into making ROMs and custom kernels for it.

Also, it looks like the Galaxy S phones either come with Gingerbread or are getting an update for it, and of course newer models will probably come with ICS as the default OS.

Comment: Yah, there are a few lightly customized ROMs (they just theme the stock ROM and add/remove some apps) but none of the XDA/cyanogenmod big boys see the SK as a good target for a kernel project, alas.

That being said, I don't regret buying mine as the physical keyboard absolutely **rocks** and for me that's a huge consideration.

Comment: I just flashed a ROM on mine today, and it looks and runs a better! No SetCPU needed. It does look like it has a custom kernel as well. 2.6.32.9-Platypus_Egg_v1

Comment: You don't say what ROM you're using, but looks like it's from sduvick's Platypus Dev Team.  I know Domination 1.5 came out recently, perhaps that's it?  Generally they're based off of the KJ2 stock ROM with a boatload of tweaks.

Comment: Yep, it's Domination 2.0. He just updated it a few days ago. It looks great, and it's pretty nice not having all that T-Mobile software taking up space.